# How can I substitute English Toffee in cookies?

Tags: substitutions, cookies, candy, toffee

I found a [cookie recipe](http://smittenkitchen.com/2008/11/chocolate-toffee-cookies/) which requires "English Toffee bars". I have never seen them around here, and don't know what they are.

What are these bars? Is there any substitution I can use? How close are Toffifee candies?

If it just said "toffee", I would cook it at home. But I am unsure what the differences are between an English toffee bar and normal toffee. Can I still cook it? How does it differ from normal toffee? Or can I just put normal toffee in the cookies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

English toffee is very chewy - the kind of stuff that glues your teeth together! Once it has been cooked and set, it's not easy to handle and wouldn't be easy to chop up for a cookie recipe. You'd possibly be better off with some kind of fudge which is easier to handle but will still hold its shape in a cookie.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a HARD bar of toffee. It often looks like a chocolate bar, as it is marked into break-off segments

[image: Toffee Bar package]

Modern "English Toffee" recipes call for toffee with a chocolate coating dusted with chopped nuts. I don't think this is really traditional English toffee

Use regular butter and sugar toffee as a substitute

Comment: Break-off segments of toffee? In 24 years living in England I don't think I ever saw something like this.

Answer (score 2):

If the origin of the recipe is American, by "English Toffee" they probably actually mean Heath Bars.  Heath Bars are, of course, chocolate-covered, but it's occasionally possible to find "bare" Heath toffee in the baking aisle of various supermarkets.

If the recipe is British or French in origin, it could refer to chewy English toffee (per Red Spatula), which is quite different.  If it's from some other country, who knows?

Comment: Yes, they mean Heath bars (it is specified in the recipe). But I have never seen them here in Germany. Any ideas for a substitute?

Comment: @rumtscho Wikipedia suggests Skor or Daim/Dime.